# 1) Trouble to remove duplicates in google calendar event every time when I refresh script editor 2) Custom menu is not working

Tags: calendar, duplicates, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a list of scheduled presentation and track the progress of each presentation (by who, when and what) by using google sheet. Meanwhile as I am creating the list, I am trying to connect it to google calendar as well so every presentation will be automatically created whenever I key into the google sheet. However, duplication happens whenever I refresh it (either running the code or debugging). I tried using **Array** and **Push** to remove the duplication but it didn't work.

On a separate issue,  my custom menu didn't work too although the UI is there. When I clicked, it says **Script function not found: schedulePresentation**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("W4").getValue(); 
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId); 
  var signups = spreadsheet.getRange("R12:T100").getValues(); 
  var existingEvents=Calendar.Events.list(calendarId);
  var eventArray=[]; 
  existingEvents.items.forEach(function(e){eventArray.push(e.summary)}); 
  for (x=0; x<signups.length; x++) {
    var shift = signups[x]; 
    var startTime = shift[0];
    var endTime = shift[1];
    var PresentationTitle = shift[2];
    if(eventArray.indexOf(PresentationTitle)==-1){
      eventCal.createEvent(PresentationTitle,new Date(startTime),new Date(endTime));
}else{
  Logger.log('event exists already');
    var startRow=12; //not sure where this is supposed to be or even needed (but the rationale for this code was to to dynamically detect the rows for duplication)
    var startColumn=20; //column T
    var rowNumber=spreadsheet.getLastRow()-startRow+1;
    var columnNumber=3;
    var signups = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn,rowNumber,columnNumber).getValues();
}
}
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Sync to Calendar')
      .addItem('Schedule Presentation', 'schedulePresentation')
      .addItem('Email shift confirmation', 'emailTeam')
      .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Delete')
          .addItem('Delete shifts from Calendar', 'clearCalendar'))
      .addToUi();
function schedulePresentation() {
}

function emailTeam() {
}

function clearCalendar() {
}
}
```

Comment: If you have two separate, not directly related issues, please post two separate questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: As for your function `myFunction` - it works for me correctly (apart from the fact that the lines `var startRow=12; ... var signups = spreadsheet.getRange(startRow,startColumn,rowNumber,columnNumber).getValues();` are superfluous), if you still get duplicates this might be due to issues like case sensitivity or spaces (e.g. `Event 1` is not the same like `event 1` or `Event 1 `).

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka, but given it's the exact same code and it runs perfectly on your side, I am not sure which part of the whole function to debug the case sensitivity/spaces issue.

Comment: If you want to avoid case sensitivity/spaces issue you need to use Regex: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp